# Arranging elements inside a div

Tags: html, css

this is driving me insane...

Basically, I have this website and I want it to have  header div that contains the name of the website, search bar, and sign in/log in buttons.
I want the logo to be on the left, search bar in the middle, and sign in and log in on the right, one on top of each other. The logo and search should be in the middle vertically.

here's what I have in code:

```css
#home {
  position: absolute;
}
#search {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
}
#search_box {
  width: 500px;
}
#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  color: beige;
  padding: 10px;
  float: top;
  margin: auto;
  border-style: groove;
}
#log_in {
  float: right;
}
#sign_in {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="home">
    <h1>HatSpace</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="search">
    <form>
      <input id="search_box" type="text" placeholder="Search the Website">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="log_in">
    <p>Log in</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sign_in">
    <p>Sign in</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is what I get after Chheda's code**

```css
#header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: burlywood;
    color: beige;
    border-style: groove;
    }
#register {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">
            <div>
                <h1><a href="index.html"</a>HatSpace</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="register">
                <form>
                    <input style = "width: 500px;" type="text" placeholder="Search the Website">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>Log in</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Sign in</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If you remove href from HatSpace element, then it will look like exactly what I want to, but I need href there, what is wrong with this!!!

Comment: And where do you want the 'Go Back' text to be?

Comment: oops that's extra, I will delete it now

Comment: I humbly suggest that you look into using a framework like Foundation or Bootstrap to build your website. They have pre-made css classes that will allow you to build out a layout grid easily without writing out a ton of custom css. Vertical alignment is also very easy if you use their flexgrid, but keep in mind that flexgrid has limited browser support. I hope this helps, and best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```css
#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
#register {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="home">
    <h1>HatSpace</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="register">
    <div id="log_in">
      <p>Log in</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sign_in">
      <p>Sign in</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="search">
    <form>
      <input id="search_box" type="text" placeholder="Search the Website">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I needed the search bar in the middle, and log in and sign in to the right, but close thanks

Comment: Well, I just changed the place of search and those sign in stuff, and it is pretty much what I needed, so thanks

Comment: There is a small problem, when I try to add href to HatSpace text, it will ruin the whole thing!!! it's weird! 
When I click on search, sign in or log in, it will open a new page that hatspace has to open!

Answer (score 0):

First, put the "Log in" and "Sign in" texts into the same container (e.g. `<div id="log_in"> </div>`).
Remove the `line-height:90px` from `#header` (I believe you added it to move the search box). Instead, add `margin-top:30px` to `#search`.
If you needed the `line-height` for `#home`, too, just add it there.

Hope this matches your needs ;)